# Update css for Modal dynamically backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, backbone.js

I am new to backbone and am trying to debug an issue. I have a Modal which is rendering as follows:

```
render: function() {
            this.$el.html(Modal.TEMPLATE);
            this.$(Modal.HEADER_TITLE_SELECTOR).html("Edit"));
            this.$(Modal.BODY_SELECTOR).append(this.myView.render().el);
            this.$(Modal.FOOTER_SELECTOR).append(Modal.BUTTON_DONE);
        },
```

The 'myView' is associated with a class (with display: block) which I want to override with (display: inline-block). How can I do that?

Comment: Why not create a `display:inline-block;` CSS rule for the associated class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
render: function() {
            this.$el.html(Modal.TEMPLATE);
            this.$(Modal.HEADER_TITLE_SELECTOR).html("Edit"));
            this.$(Modal.BODY_SELECTOR).append(this.myView.render().el);
            this.myView.$el.css("display", "inline-block");
            //or this.$(this.myView.$el).css("display", "inline-block")
            this.$(Modal.FOOTER_SELECTOR).append(Modal.BUTTON_DONE);
        },
```

Comment: I think I  figured similar way above. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue:

$(this.myView.$el).css({display: 'inline-block'});